# Didn't receive notification when someone edited/commented on the post

Tags: support, notifications

I didn't receive a notification on my question when someone (the answerer) commented on his answer and edited that answer. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Unless you were the last person to comment on that answer before the comment or you were `@`'d - you don't get notified of comments on answers to your questions.

Comment: @JonClements FTFW - "Unless you were the only other person..." (or is last-commenter-notification also a thing?).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. There is a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231204/295232) asking to enable this (for answer edits). Whenever I would make a *significant* edit to one of my answers, I often write a comment (either on my own answer, with an [@-reply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/295232) if they have commented on my answer, or on the question itself) to make sure they read it.

Comment: Might be worth noting the @ reply will only work if they've already commented on the answer.

Comment: Yeah, good idea. You usually see something's amiss when the @ doesn't autocomplete.